# Dpkg remains configuring moodle

Tags: kubuntu, dpkg, 10.04, aptitude, moodle

When I tried to configure moodle like:

```
root@server:~# dpkg --configure moodle
```

It remains like that indefinitely. Watching this process on `top` I realized that it does not use any Memory capacity and the CPU capacity use by this process ranges from 4 to 10.

I am using Kubuntu server 10.04 Lucid with Linux kernel 2.6.32-24-server

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google shows a few people struggling with the older versions of Moodle. And looking at [a package search for `moodle`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=moodle&searchon=names&section=all), 10.04 ships a pretty ancient version.

There's almost certainly value in dumping the package version (with `sudo apt-get purge moodle`) and grabbing the official version from [moodle.org](https://moodle.org/). This will mean you'll need to go through [the documentation](http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/Main_page) manually and look after the install in the long term but these are honestly things you should be considering anyway.

Alternatively you might have more luck with a more modern version of Ubuntu. 10.04 is only supported until next year anyway, so an upgrade to 12.04 (and then 14.04 soon) might be the best course of action.